# IE 9 ignoring conditional jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have the following conditional comment on my site:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/ie-wbr.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The corresponding jquery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("<br />").insertAfter(".entry-title wbr");
});
```

This works perfectly for ie8, but ie9 is ignoring it. I don't know whether it's an issue with the jquery or the conditional comment.

Comment: which jquery version are you using?

Comment: insert an alert inside the ready function... then you can be sure if IE9 is ignoring the conditional statement or not.

Comment: does ie9 support the `wbr` tag?

Comment: ie8 and ie9 don't support it, but they both seem to recognise it. Good idea about the alert, will try that.

Comment: Alert works in ie8 and not in ie9, so it must be ignoring the comment for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've been a complete idiot. The machine I'm checking on is ie11.